# SWT Events delegate from a shell to a SWT.Browser

Tags: java, browser, swt, mozilla, xulrunner

Imagine you have a `SWT.Browser` and want to create a `DropTarget`.

The Problem I encountered is the following:
Neither the `Shell` nor the `Display` gets the drop-event, because the browsercontrol consumes it.

My Idea was to put something invisible on top of the browser. This should consume the events. But for this case it seems, as if I have to deliver all mouse events to the SWT-Browser.

Now I am stuck, because I don't get the notification running. I have a mousemove listener running. All events on that schell are captured.

How can I resend this events to the browser `notifyListener(int type, Event e)` does not work for a `SWT.Mozilla` browser (in eclipse 3.4.2). I know this eclipse framework is incredible old, but that version is delivered by IBM lotus notes 9.

How can I dispatch these events?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Display.post()`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html&anchor=post%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event%29) to dispatch events to SWT.

Comment: It seems that there is only one Display, so if post events, my listener will get them again but the browser not.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach It seems like the control that has the focus receives the event. Try calling `browser.setFocus();` and `browser.forceFocus();` before posting the `Event`.

Comment: Unfortunatly this did not fix the problem. It may be problematic, because an SWT-Broser (actually mozilla) may not work with the focus.